# Java - read structured binary file

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and a I need to read a binary file and display its contents converted as integers. The file has this structure:

```
{client#, position 1, size 32 | 
category, position 33, size 10 | 
type, position 43, size 10 | 
creditlimit, position 53, size 20}
```

I need just a guide on what classes to use and a convertion example, a little snipet will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the little snippet of code you have tried.

Comment: When you say binary file, do you mean a text file as above or true, binary data (e.g., bytes in some encoding that is not text)?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that position 1 actually is 0; the first byte.
Also it seems the file format is of **fixed size** records, probably with ASCII in the bytes.
To check the data, I start with taking the fields in Strings. Converting them to long/int could loose information on the actual content.

The following uses a sequential binary file. Faster would be a memory mapped file, but this is acceptable and short.

Hold the client data:

```
class Client {
    String clientno;
    String category; 
    String type;
    String position;
    String creditlimit;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Client# %s, categ %s, type %s, pos %s, creditlimit %s%n",
            clientno, category, type, position, creditlimit);
    }
}
```

Read the file:

```
// Field sizes:
final int CLIENT_NO = 32;
final int CATEGORY = 10;
final int TYPE = 10;
final int CREDIT_LIMIT = 20;
final int RECORD_SIZE = CLIENT_NO + CATEGORY + TYPE + CREDIT_LIMIT;

byte[] record = new byte[RECORD_SIZE];
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(file))) {

    for (;;) {
         int nread = in.read(record);
         if (nread < RECORD_SIZE) {
             break;
         }
         Client client = new Client();
         int offset = 0;
         int offset2 = offset + CLIENT_NO;
         client.clientno = recordField(record, offset, offset2 - offset);
         offset = offset2;
         int offset2 = offset + CATEGORY;
         client.category = recordField(record, offset, offset2 - offset);
         offset = offset2;
         int offset2 = offset + TYPE;
         client.type = recordField(record, offset, offset2 - offset);
         offset = offset2;
         int offset2 = offset + CREDITLIMIT;
         client.creditlimit = recordField(record, offset, offset2 - offset);

         System.out.println(client);
    }

} // Closes in.
```

with a field extraction:

```
private static String recordField(byte[] record, int offset, int length) {
    String field = new String(record, offset, length, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    // Use ASCII NUL as string terminator:
    int pos = field.indexOf('\u0000');
    if (pos != -1) {
        field = field.substring(0, pos);
    }

    return field.trim(); // Trim also spaces for fixed fields.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correct, you should use the [NIO Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).
With the `asIntBuffer()` from the byteBuffer class, you can get an `IntBuffer` view of a `ByteBuffer`. And by calling `get(int[] dst)` you could convert it to integers.

The initial `ByteBuffer` is available by using `file channels`.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with binary data, may be [JBBP](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) will be comfortable way for you, to parse and print the data structure with the framework is very easy (if I understood the task correctly and you work with byte fields), the example parsing whole input stream and then print parsed data to console

```
@Bin class Record {byte [] client; byte [] category;  byte [] type; byte [] creditlimit;};
@Bin class Records {Record [] records;};
Records parsed = JBBPParser.prepare("records [_] {byte [32] client; byte [10] category; byte [10] type; byte [20] creditlimit;}").parse(THE_INPUT_STREAM).mapTo(Records.class);
System.out.println(new JBBPTextWriter().Bin(parsed).toString());
```